# How do I use digitalWrite in pyFirmata?

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to write a bit of code using pyFirmata and this is what I import

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
```

However, I need to use the function digitalWrite which is available in arduino. Does anyone know what the code is in pyfirmata?

Comment: Create a `pyfirmata.Pin` object and use `read` and `write`.

Comment: [hint](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/72954273/how-can-i-rtfm.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is literally explained on the first page of the pyfirmata manual.

https://pyfirmata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> #### Usage
>
> ### Basic usage:
>
> ```
> from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
> board = Arduino('/dev/tty.usbserial-A6008rIF')
> board.digital[13].write(1)
> ```
>
> ...
> If you use a pin more often, it can be worth it to use the get_pin
> method of the board. It let’s you specify what pin you need by a
> string, composed of ‘a’ or ‘d’ (depending on wether you need an analog
> or digital pin), the pin number, and the mode (‘i’ for input, ‘o’ for
> output, ‘p’ for pwm). All seperated by :. Eg. a:0:i for analog 0 as
> input, or d:3:p for digital pin 3 as pwm.:
>
> ```
> analog_0 = board.get_pin('a:0:i')
> analog_0.read()
> 0.661440304938
> pin3 = board.get_pin('d:3:p')
> pin3.write(0.6)
> ```